# drawing UML class diagram does not work proper with tikz-uml /pgfsetlayers

Tags: tikz-pgf

i'm stuck and have no glue whats the problem. I'd like to draw a UML class diagram with tkz-uml package. Sadly my result is not how it should be. I try to get the example running, using following code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,article,oneside]{memoir}

%% Package
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,sorting=nyt,language=ngerman, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[german]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfloat}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{listings} 
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsmath}


%% TiKz Stuff %%%
\usetikzlibrary{calc, decorations.pathmorphing,decorations.pathreplacing, fadings, shadings, shapes, arrows, positioning,patterns,automata}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{umlpackage}{p}
\begin{umlpackage}{sp1}
\umlclass[template=T]{A}{n : uint \\ t : float}{}
\umlclass[y=-3]{B}{  d : double}{  \umlvirt{setB(b : B) : void} \\ getB() : B}
\end{umlpackage}
\begin{umlpackage}[x=10,y=-6]{sp2}
\umlinterface{C}{  n : uint \\ s : string}{}
\end{umlpackage}
\umlclass[x=2,y=-10]{D}{  n : uint  }{}
\end{umlpackage}

\umlassoc[geometry=-|-, arg1=tata, mult1=*, pos1=0.3, arg2=toto, mult2=1, pos2=2.9, align2=left]{C}{B}
\umlunicompo[geometry=-|, arg=titi, mult=*, pos=1.7, stereo=vector]{D}{C}
\umlimport[geometry=|-, anchors=90 and 50, name=import]{sp2}{sp1}
\umlaggreg[arg=tutu, mult=1, pos=0.8, angle1=30, angle2=60, loopsize=2cm]{D}{D}
\umlinherit[geometry=-|]{D}{B}
\umlnote[x=2.5,y=-6, width=3cm]{B}{Kommentar zu classe B}
\umlnote[x=7.5,y=-2]{import-2}{blubber die blub}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:

[image: LaTex output]

But it should look similar to this example:

[image]

Somebody a constructive idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of saying that you are using `\documentclass…` compose a full [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/a/3225/16595). Does the problem persist if you use `article` or even `standalone`? Anyways, with [`tikz-uml v0.99`](http://www.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en&id=download) the output is as expected (blue background, connecting lines, …).

Comment: yes, the blue background and the lines are missing. this is my actual problem. i'll post a full MWE in a minute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Load `tikz-uml` after you declared your layers.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background,foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlpackage}{p}
\begin{umlpackage}{sp1}
\umlclass[template=T]{A}{n : uint \\ t : float}{}
\umlclass[y=-3]{B}{  d : double}{  \umlvirt{setB(b : B) : void} \\ getB() : B}
\end{umlpackage}
\begin{umlpackage}[x=10,y=-6]{sp2}
\umlinterface{C}{  n : uint \\ s : string}{}
\end{umlpackage}
\umlclass[x=2,y=-10]{D}{  n : uint  }{}
\end{umlpackage}

\umlassoc[geometry=-|-, arg1=tata, mult1=*, pos1=0.3, arg2=toto, mult2=1, pos2=2.9, align2=left]{C}{B}
\umlunicompo[geometry=-|, arg=titi, mult=*, pos=1.7, stereo=vector]{D}{C}
\umlimport[geometry=|-, anchors=90 and 50, name=import]{sp2}{sp1}
\umlaggreg[arg=tutu, mult=1, pos=0.8, angle1=30, angle2=60, loopsize=2cm]{D}{D}
\umlinherit[geometry=-|]{D}{B}
\umlnote[x=2.5,y=-6, width=3cm]{B}{Kommentar zu classe B}
\umlnote[x=7.5,y=-2]{import-2}{blubber die blub}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: thanks, 1 min ago i figured out that the source of trouble is the {pgflayers}-environment. Your tip worked very well. :D